# Docker-Compose Output File To Local Host

Tags: python, docker-compose

I have the below `docker-compose.yaml` file that sets up a database and runs a python script

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    cap_add:
      - SYS_NICE
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=test_db
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=xxx
    ports:
      - '3310:3310'
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
  py_service:
    container_name: test_py
    build: .
    command: ./main.py -r compute_init
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 80:80
    environment:
      DB_HOST: db
      DB_PORT: 3306
      DB_USER: root
      DB_PASSWORD: xxx
      DB_NAME: test_db
    links:
      - db
    volumes:
      - py_output:/app/output
volumes:
  db:
    driver: local
  py_output:
```

To run it I perform the following

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
docker-compose run -v /home/ubuntu/docker_directory/output:/app/output/* py_service
```

Here is the Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY env/requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["python3","main.py","-r","compute_init"]
```

Now this works fine I can see the data has been properly populated under the generated in the msql database.
The python file at the end of the script should dump a csv file to `/app/ouput/output.csv` (via pandas library `df.to_csv("output/output.csv")`)
My question is, how to recover that csv from the container to the local directory.
The script seems to finish off without any errors, but can't find the output file at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems using `docker-compose run -v $(pwd)/output:/app/output py_service`
did the job